# How to fire trigger after every insert - Oracle (Bulk insert)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, mutating-table

I want the trigger to run after each and every record that gets inserted.

This validation works fine if I have a simple insert like this:

```
insert into g_dossier values
               (112334, 'BBT', 'LPO','TTS','Y') ;
```

However, when it’s like a bulk insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO g_piece(
                refpiece,
                typpiece,
                class_piece
                group_piece
                flag_piere)    
SELECT         :new.element_num,
                PROC_TYPE,
                DECODE( piece_it, 'F', 'FTTR', 'N', 'FTTR', NULL ),
                DECODE( piece_it, 'T', 'TTSN', 'N', 'TTSN', NULL ),
                'N'
FROM    t_elements
WHERE   :new.db_piece_flag = 'Y';
```

The trigger mutates. I want that the validation also work when done as a bulk insert.

The query causing this problem is

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO existing_cmcl_cnt
FROM g_piece cmcl
WHERE cmcl.class_piece= :new.class_piece
```

The problem is that this query is called in a trigger applied on the same table "g_piece".  When I proceed with a simple insert (insert into g_piece values(...)), I do not have this problem.

How can I avoid this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you should change the query and insert the result of a `SELECT ... FROM some join`, not using a trigger at all. You want that when inserting into table `X`, a trigger also inserts into the same table, which is not possible (it would recurse).

If you cannot change the query, you should rename your table, create a view to the table with the old name, and create a `TRIGGER INSTEAD OF INSERT ON that view FOR EACH ROW`
that would `INSERT INTO into the real table` the result of a `SELECT ... FROM some join`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Oracle 11G, you can take a look to Compound triggers to avoid the mutating-table error. Take a look:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#CIHEFGFD